# How to position div at the bottom of a page

Tags: jquery, html, css, position

How can I set position of a `<div>` to the bottom of page with either CSS or jQuery?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` and `bottom:0`

### Check working example. http://jsfiddle.net/gyExR/

Comment: If the page is longer than the viewport, the `div` will overlap the content. To fix this problem, check out this example: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/bottom-footer-demo.htm

Comment: Another source to learn about the _"exception to the rule"_ cases is CSS-tricks: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: This example is not working for pages with scrollbar

Answer (score 6):

You can use `position:absolute;bottom:0;` if that's all you want.

Answer (score 2):

in css: **position:absolute** or **position:fixed**

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered already, but to give a little bit more context for non CSS-experts:

Given the HTML

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Some content</p>
    <div class="footer">down there</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

then the following css

```
div.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

will position the text at the lower right corner of your viewport (browser window). Scrolling will move the footer text.

If you use

```
div.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

on the other hand, the footer will stay at the bottom of your viewport, even if you scroll. The same technique can be used with `top: 0` and `left: 0` btw, to position an element at the top left corner.

Answer (score 1):

The combination `position:fixed;` with `bottom:0;` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```css
    html{
      min-height:100%;
      position:relative;
      background-color:red;
    }
    .footer{
      bottom:0;
      position:absolute;
      background-color:blue;
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='footer'>
    <h1>I am Footer</h1>
    </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```