# How to place a footer at the bottom of a page in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I tried to create a page footer for each page. The objectif is to center the footer and to place it at the bottom of the page. You can check my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xzb9m48/1/), or see the code directly as following.

**HTML**

```
<div id="page1" class="page">
  <div class="footer">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.page {
    height: 300px;
    width: 180px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
div.footer {
    background-color: #DDD;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0; /* doesn't work */
}
p {
    width: 15px;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I saw to similar question about [How to position div at the bottom of a page ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548142/how-to-position-div-at-the-bottom-of-a-page). However, when i applied its proposition, **bottom** + **position** setting, footers in each page are all merged together, placed at the bottom of the navigator's windows. Here's the related [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xzb9m48/2/)

Can somebody help ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: you need to add `position:relative` to page div and `position:absolute` to footer div

Comment: @AlessandroIncarnati There is no need to comment just to say that you have created an answer. The questioner is automatically notified of it (and it is not difficult to scroll down and figure it out by yourself!).

Comment: @Sverri M. Olsen Sometimes I found it useful if users were not answering straight away to send them an additional notification. Thanks anyway for pointing that out. :) Happy answering.

Comment: @AlessandroIncarnati If they do not respond to the first notification then a second one is not going to make a difference. It is not a popularity contest. Just add your answer and let people evaluate and respond to it at their leisure.

Comment: @Sverri M. Olsen : Thanks for your feedback. Anyway it's not for popularity that I post answers. I like to have a direct communication with the user asking the question. Simple as that. There are plenty of questions that you can look into providing solutions to help users. Happy answering. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing ***position: relative;*** applied to the *class="page"*.
This way the element which has absolute position applied knows that needs to be bottom:0 relative to the parent element .page.

```
div.page {
    height: 300px;
    width: 180px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
}
div.footer {
    background-color: #DDD;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0; /* it works now */
    position: absolute;
}
p {
    width: 15px;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/9xzb9m48/3/

Comment: Thanks Lars, obviously. I was relying on the Jsfiddle which had position absolute in the code.

Comment: thanks for your answer Alessandro, fast and simple. happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
div.page {
  height: 300px;
  width: 180px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
div.footer {
  background-color: #DDD;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
p {
  width: 15px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ushma, your answer is right, but I can only accept one answer. have a nice day ! :)

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.